# Can we use be in its basic form without any auxiliary verb?

Tags: grammar, subjunctives, imperative-sentences

**Be** can be used without auxiliary

But for commands. For example

> Be cool
>   Be stylish
>   Be as you are

But what about this sentence

> Peace be upon you?

Answer (score 1):

As you note, the imperative in English is formed using the bare infinitive form of the verb, and with no subject.

> Be good!
>
> Eat your greens.

The subjunctive (expressing hopes or desires) is also formed with the bare infinitive, but when forming the subjunctive you need to subject:

> Peace be upon you.
>
> God save the King!

These are not commands, they express desires. We hope that God will save the King. We don't command him (imperative), nor do we state that "God does save the King" (indicative).

The subjunctive is now very rare in English. It is most often found in fixed expressions like these, and can often be avoided by using phrases like "I hope that..."

Comment: Shouldn't there be a comma after god. .      God, save the king

Comment: @user236989 - No comma. "God save the King!" is a shortened form of "May God save the King!"

Comment: @user236989: If you included the comma then it would become an imperative, a command addressed to God.  But the usual form is "God save the King!", which - as James K explained - isn't a command, isn't an imperative, but is rather a subjunctive.

Comment: Be that as it may... I'd suggest that we all be aware of classic usage such as "Blessed be the name of the LORD from this time forth and for evermore".